# Assignments are by reference?

Tags: java, c++, variable-assignment

In java if you do

```
Myobj one = new Myobj();
Myobj two = one;
```

Then one and two are pointing to the same object.

In C++ if I did:

```
Myobj one = new Myobj();
Myobj *two = &one;
```

Is this essentially the same as the java example? Wherein modifying either `one` or `two` will effect both objects?

Comment: No, this can't compile : `two` should be declared `Myobj*`, and then just do `one = two;` . You can also use references in C++ .

Comment: @quantdev Well I don't actually want `one = two` but when I initialize `two`, I want it to be a copy of `one`. Then I can edit `two` later on. Did I do this correctly?

Comment: @user1008134 one is currently a pointer to nothing

Comment: @user1008134 Your code would not even compile. You assign a pointer to an object (second line) and then even the address of a pointer to a dereferenced object (which does not exist, you can only dereference a pointer).

Comment: @Winestone Corrected it, I mistyped it

Comment: After your correction, there is still this problem: new returns a pointer, you cannot assign it to the object "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These make one and two basically the same thing:

```
Myobj *one = new Myobj();
Myobj *two = one;
//one and two are the same thing, pointer's to a Myobj

Myobj one;
Myobj *two = &one;
//one is an object that will be deallocated at end of current scope
//two is a pointer to one
```

In C++ `new Myobj()` creates a `Myobj` on the heap and returns a pointer to it.

```
Myobj *one; //Creates a variable that should point to a Myobj instance
Myobj two = new Myobj(); //Doesn't really work
*two = &one; //Get where two point's at and assign the location of one to it
```

Update:

```
Myobj one = new Myobj(); //This doesn't quite work, assigning pointer to class
Myobj *two = &one; //This works, you make a pointer to point to one
```

To fix your first statement, you could use:

```
Myobj one = Myobj();
//Myobj one(); //This requires the constructor to take arguments, thanks juanchopanza!
Myobj one{}; //Requires C++11, courtesy juanchopanza
Myobj one;
```

All do the same thing

Generally, the following should make a copy:

```
Myobj one; //or any variant
Myobj two = one;
```

Or if you prefer to use pointers:

```
Myobj *one = new Myobj();
Myobj *two = new Myobj();
*two = *one;
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked this question poorly, but what would be the proper way to make a copy of `one` into `two` without making them the same variable.

Comment: Just to clarify, your last two code snippets make two separate objects each with the same contents but modifying one or the other will not effect the other one?

Comment: `Myobj one();` is a function declaration.

Comment: BTW you can say `Myobj one{};` (unless stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler.)

Answer (score 2):

theses code below is same as Java.

```
Myobj one;
Myobj& two = one;
```

Answer (score 2):

They are not same!

Objects created with `new` keyword persist even after the local scope. They are allocated storage in heap. And they return a reference so you need a pointer to store the reference value.

Objects created

`without`  `new` keyword follow copy semantics. That is if you have

```
Object obj1=Object()
Object obj2=obj1;
```

two objects will be created. That is property values of obj1 are copied to obj2.

If you do not want to create a new object, you should use pointers.

Ex:

```
Object obj1=Object()
Object *obj1ref=&obj1;  //this is like assigning reference in java
```

Below statement illustrates variable in cpp note `&` in declaration, it cannot be mapped to any other object once assigned. So it's `not` too close to `Java` references.

```
Object& ref2=obj1;
```

Here obj1 has lifetime which ends after local scope.

When you declare like Object obj in cpp, you are actually allocating space for one object you are not just creating a reference like in `Java`. In `CPP`, pointers are closest to what you call references in java.

```
 Object *obj=new Object();
```

Above statement creates the object in memory other than stack. It has life time until you free the memory using `delete` operator or until the application is closed.

In `Java`, all objects are created in heap only.

Answer (score 2):

Below code makes one and two point to same location i.e changing either will change both of them.

```
yobj *one = new Myobj();
Myobj *two = one;
```

If you want two to be a copy of one then,

```
Myobj *one = new Myobj();
Myobj *two = new Myobj();
*two = *one;
```